# Active Directory: How to let a group manage another group

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy

I have a group (`group1`) containing users.
In real life, this group is handled by two people (`group1-leads`).

I want `group1-leads` to be able to manage `group1`.

So I double-click on `group1` navigate to the `Managed By` tab and change to `group1-leads`.

However when I click "OK", I get an error message telling me:

> An object (User) with the following name cannot be found:
>   `group1-leads`... bla bla bla

How do I set a group in this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in the Windows Server 2003 Administration Tools Pack.

I had to install the "Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2 Administration Tools Pack": http://winadminnotes.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/how-to-add-a-group-to-the-managed-by-field/

Answer (score 1):

The same effect can be accomplished by setting a custom AD right. I don't have AD in front of me right now so I don't have the exact attribute needed, so please bear with me.

If you go into the Group you want to be managed, go to the Security tab and hit Advanced.

1. Click the Add a new privilege button.
2. Enter the group you want to manage this group
3. In the big list, search for Group Membership, members, or something like that.
4. Check the 'allow' box next to it.

This will allow the second group to manage the membership of the first group. This won't be reflected in the "Managed By" tab, though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just search for the group by clicking the Advanced and Find Now buttons? That will allow you to browse your users and groups and select the appropriate group, as maybe you're typing the name incorrectly.

Comment: The form only lets me search in "Users" and "Contacts" object types.

Comment: sam in the find window, click the drop-down next to Find: and select what you'd like (try common queries or custom).